# What do I need to do in order to get python-mode.el-6.0.5 to find python3.2? (Using OS X Lion)

Tags: osx-lion, emacs23, python-3.2, python-mode

I get the message that it can't be found when I try to open a python 3.2 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

should it happen with latest release or trunk
please file a report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

giving some more details